# Compare string columns in pandas Dataset and extracting unmatched values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset of multiple columns where I want to compare one column Named `df.BRAND` to every entry of `df.my_Brand` and if the entry of `df.BRAND` didn't match any entry of `df.my_Brand`, I want to shift `df.BRAND` value to another column named `df.New_DESCRIPTION` and if it matches the value then I want to keep it as it is.

| BRAND | NEW_DESCRIPTION | my_Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USE 615880.ATT GROUND ROD | HOISTING GRIP FOR PWRT-608 POWER CABLE, CEQ.7... | 123EWIRELESS |
| COMMSCOPE |  | 3M Products |
| ELECTRO-WIRE INC. | TELCOFLEX II 6 AWG L2 GREEN, KS24194-SOUTHWIR. | COMMSCOPE |
| GALTRONICS | 12 X 12' GRIP SPAN ICE BRIDGE | o-m6 Technologies |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am new to python and don't know how to proceed, Here is the code I was trying:

```
df_Brand['BRAND'] = [y if x == '' else x for x,y in zip(df_Brand['BRAND'],df_Brand['my_Brand'])]
```

Any solution code will be helpful as I am not sure if the code I was trying is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

`df['NEW_DESCRIPTION']=[df['BRAND'][i] if df['BRAND'][i] not in list(df['my_Brand']) else '' for i in range(len(df))]`

Comment: The above code replaced df.NEW_DESCRIPTION values with df.BRAND values after running this code.